# Why is this sort string by chars frequency code not working?

Tags: python, sorting

So the question is: Given a string, sort it in decreasing order based on the frequency of characters.

Ex: "tree"
returns: "eert" or "eetr" both are valid answers

So my thought process is to create a counter to hold freq numbers, then sort by freq, in reverse order. However, it's not passing all testcases. For example, it works on "tree" but does not work on "longeststringhere", returns "eeengststrngrloih" which is not a valid answer because all the same characters must be grouped together. Thoughts on why my code doesn't work...?

Code:

```
class Solution:
    def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
        freq = collections.Counter(s)
        return "".join(sorted(list(s), key = lambda x: freq[x], reverse = True))
```

Comment: Ah, clarification - the letters must be grouped together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect dreamcrash's approach to be faster, but a quick fix for your approach is to explicitly sort by frequency, *then by the value itself*. (As a side note: `sorted` can be called on any iterable, exactly because it doesn't need to care about the internal structure of that iterable.)

```
class Solution:
    def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
        freq = collections.Counter(s)
        return "".join(sorted(s, key = lambda x: (freq[x], x), reverse = True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
    freq = collections.Counter(s)
    sorted_by_value = dict(sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
    return''.join([char * freq[char] for char in sorted_by_value])
```

First, we get the number of times that each characters shows up:

```
freq = collections.Counter(s)
```

then we sorted by value

```
sorted_by_value = dict(sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
```

Finally, we iterate over each character (*i.e.,* key of the map) and repeat that character "value" times, and join everything together into a string:

```
return''.join([char * freq[char] for char in sorted_by_value])
```

**Output:**

```
eeennggssttrrloih
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the string had duplicate letters the lookup would happen more than once. To fix the problem, just remove all but the first instance of a character.

```py
class Solution:
    def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
        freq = collections.Counter(s)
        return "".join(sorted(list(dict.fromkeys(list(s))) key = lambda x: freq[x], reverse = True))
```

Returns 'engstrloih'

A nicer way of writing that is:

```py
class Solution:
    def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
        freq = collections.Counter(s)
        unique_letters = list(dict.fromkeys(list(s)))
        return "".join(sorted(unique_letters, key = lambda x: freq[x], reverse = True))
```

Comment: Ah, needed a slight clarification - the letters need to be grouped together. So you do want multiple characters, but the characters themselves need to be grouped, and in order of frequency (highest to lowest). So "longeststringhere" would return something like "eeennggssttrrloih"

between your and Karl's comments I'm starting to get a clue of why it's not working - how do I utilize the sort function to group all the same characters together?

Comment: The spec was pretty loose. Many different results would satisfy the requirements as stated.

Comment: Yes, got it. Needed to change it to sorted(list(s), key = lambda x: (freq[x], x), reverse = True)

to group the characters. Thanks @Mike, Karl, and @dreamcrash! :)